# React js and Mongodb web application getting error?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux, redux-thunk

Proxy error: Could not proxy request /api/games from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:8080/ (ECONNREFUSED).

code in action.js (Redux)

```js
export function fetchGames(){
    return dispatch =>{
        fetch('/api/games')
    }
}
```

```js
import express from 'express';
import mongodb from 'mongodb';

const app = express();
const dbUrl = 'mongodb://onkar localhost:27017/crudwithredux';

mongodb.MongoClient.connect(dbUrl, function(err, db) {

  app.get('/api/games', (req, res) => {
    db.collection('games').find({}).toArray((err, games) => {
      res.json({ games });
    });
  });

  app.listen(8080, () => console.log('Server is running on localhost:8080'));

});
```

**  Hi i m onkar, I am new in react js. i getting error in server page. I have mongo db database so i m retrieve the data from mongo db. and show in Json format in react js using redux.**

Comment: Server is down ?

Comment: Hi @Onkar please add more information to the issue you are having so that the community can help you. With the code that you have provided there is no enough information for us to help you. How is your server configured? is there any other request that works and this is the only one that doesn't? is it a MERN stack? where is fetchGames being called? how are you configuring the proxy? is it built using webpack? which versions of the components are you using? etc. The more information, the faster you can get help ;)

Comment: Is `mongod` running?

Comment: You'll need to provide more information about the server running on 8080, this isn't really related to react at all.

Comment: Does it work if you use `curl` or a rest client?

Comment: seems your server is not running